# PDF UA-1, all fonts, even the base 14 fonts have to embedded error?

Tags: xml, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

I am getting an PDFConformanceException while creating a PDF file from XSL-FO template parsing an XML data. My Exception as follows:

```
    (Location of error unknown)org.apache.fop.pdf.PDFConformanceException: For PDF/UA-l,
all fonts, even the base 14 fonts, have to be embedded! Offending font: Helvetica/Bold
```

Here is my XSL-FO file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.1"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
  <xsl:template match="root">
  <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page">
        <fo:region-body margin="1in"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>

    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block>Hello, <xsl:value-of select="name" />!</fo:block>
        <fo:block>
            <fo:table>
                 <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
            text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                        <fo:block>
                            No.
                            </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
            text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                        <fo:block>
                            Name
                            </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" 
            text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                        <fo:block>
                            Phone Number
                            </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row>
                  <xsl:for-each select="./friend">
                    <xsl:for-each select="./closefriends">
                    <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
                            </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="../name" />
                          <xsl:value-of select="names" />
                            </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="phNo" />
                            </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                 </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
  </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also we have registered the fonts on the fop configuration files as well. Please help me to find the root cause of the issue.

I want to know that, What I am missing here...?

Comment: I think in this case the issue is more likely in the fop configuration, please double-check it for valid `embed-url` attributes, and please state what fop version you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. we are using fop version 2.1 and let me try to put font style and family on the xsl-fo template...

Comment: For me it took a little bit of experimentation to get the right font-triplets... check the final pdf in acrobat reader and see what fonts it does not find "embedded", and note that xsl-fo might default some to "serif" or "sansserif" that you want to be like Times-Roman or Helvetica in the end.

Comment: Font issue got resolved and now I am facing a new issue...org.apache.fop.events.loggingeventlistener processevent rendered page#1. Any help on this...?

Comment: Probably worth a new question  - would you mind posting your answer for the font issue?

Comment: Yeah sure...I have added font-family attribute on the root of the xsl-fo template as <fo:root font-family="Arial"> resolved my issue.